# Clipping/Masking a MapView on Android

Tags: android, canvas, android-mapview, masking, clipping

I am trying to show a MapView as a circle on Android just like that:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Path path = new Path();
    path.addCircle(400,200,100,Direction.CW);
    canvas.clipPath(path);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Unfortunately the MapView (v2: `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView`) component seems to ignore that and instead just taking the bounds/rect of that circle to draw the map :(

I've been searching the web for a while now, not finding a nice solution for that.

Is this even possible? (The Blundell solution is not working for me because I want the background to be visible around the map)

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Android supports a hardware acceleration since API level 11. The problem is that not all drawing operations are supported when hardware acceleration is turned on. And `Canvas.clipPath` is one of them. Complete list of unsupported operations can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html)

You can try to implement what you want without using `clipPath` or just disable hardware acceleration.

To disable hardware acceleration on application level make sure you have `targetSdkVersion` 11 or higher and use `hardwareAccelerated` tag in the `AndroidManifest`:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false" ...>
```

You can disable hardware acceleration only for the particular view using the following method.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void enableHardwareAcceleration(View view, boolean enabled) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        if (enabled) {
            view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        } else {
            view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you have to use `TargetApi` annotation and check if device android version is `Honeycomb` or higher, otherwise `Eclipse` may produce an error.

If code from your question isn't working try to replace it with this:

```
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Path path = new Path();
    int count = canvas.save();

    path.addCircle(400,200,100,Direction.CW);

    canvas.clipPath(path);
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restoreToCount(count);
}
```

Comment: I am using API Level 8 (2.2) is there already a thing like hardware acceleration? I cannot find the method `setLayerType(...)` and putting the `android:hardwareAcceleration` tag into the manifest leads to errors. What do I do?

Comment: You have to change `targetSdkVersion` to higher value (11 at least)

Comment: But I want my app to be available for phones since API-8. Is there another solution? I am using the Support Framework for Fragments and stuff - anything in there that may help me? :(

Comment: you can set `minSdkVersion` to 8 and `targetSdkVersion` to 11. In this case the app will be available on devices with Android 2.2 and you will be able to use new API features

Comment: I am really sorry for bothering you again, but I actually have `targetSdkVersion` set to `17` and though no access to the `hardwareAcceleration` tag or methods :(

Comment: Also, when I am running the app on an earlier version, such as 2.3.3 where hardware acceleration is no issue, the clipping does not seem to work at all...

Comment: Actually everything works fine on my Nexus 4. Running the same thing on the Desire Z (2.3.7) shows no effect at all (also when I change the clipping to `clipRect(...)` only, meaning that there's no clipping at all)

Comment: have you tried to override `dispatchDraw` instead of `onDraw`?

Comment: Yep I currently use `dispatchDraw`. The weird thing however is that if I start another Activity from that one and shortly after that returning back, then the clipping works! `LogCat` says dispatchDraw is called both times :( What's the difference?

Comment: unfortunately, i don't know any other reasons for that =(

Comment: its not working on Android version 4.1.2  as I tested on device Samsung GT -S7262

Comment: In this way, we'll create a new `Path` object in every single dispatchDraw(Canvas) call, which might not be a good idea. It might be better to extract the `Path` out as a field, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31064523/1819810)