# Android - Creating a circular mask on video

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, mask

I'm relatively new to Android development, and I was wondering if it's possible to mask a VideoView into a shape. This is what I have so far:

### Expected Result

[image: Expected Results (Mockup)]

[image: Actual Results]

My XML for video view and layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#0088ff"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".VideoPlayerActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_mask"
        android:foreground="@drawable/circular_mask" >

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Mask shape xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

    <corners android:radius="10dp" />

</shape>
```

Main java:

```
package com.example.webmvideo;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Uri srcPath = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.webmvideo/" + R.raw.test);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final VideoView videoView = (VideoView) 
                findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

        videoView.setVideoURI(srcPath);

        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new 
                MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()  {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {                         
                String TAG = null;
                Log.i(TAG , "Duration = " + videoView.getDuration());
            }
        });     
        videoView.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the shape to circle in the mask shape XML file?

Comment: you're sending frames to the Surface, and rendering into the View (which is normally just a transparent "hole"). The blending between the View and the Surface will be done by the system compositor, so the app rendering doesn't have any prior contents to blend with. Select a mode where you're setting the alpha in the output pixels to be transparent or opaque as appropriate.

Comment: Hi Jamesbar Did you implemented rounded VideoView? If you implemented means please share you idea. how could do that?

Comment: an easy approach http://stackoverflow.com/a/28108447/3496570

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turns out it is possible to clip a video into a circle. What you're going to want to do is create your own **SurfaceView** class and override **dispatchDraw** from here you can call **canvas.clipPath** and pass in a **Path** object that contains the circle you want the video to be masked to.

Here's the view:

```
public class CircleSurface extends SurfaceView {

    private Path clipPath;

    public CircleSurface(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CircleSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CircleSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        clipPath = new Path();
        //TODO: define the circle you actually want
        clipPath.addCircle(710, 330, 250, Path.Direction.CW);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.clipPath(clipPath);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Here's what the activity might look like

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    CircleSurface surface;
    MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        surface = (CircleSurface) findViewById(R.id.surface);
        SurfaceHolder holder = surface.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);

        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yourvideo);
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        player.setDisplay(holder);
        player.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        //TODO: handle this
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        //TODO: handle this
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this seems to have nop effect

Comment: My mistake, this will not work if you have setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);

Comment: Why should super.dispatchDraw() method be after canvas.clipPath()?

Comment: Why can'y you use an ordinary View here instead of SurfaceView?

Answer (score 2):

I've done something like this mask before. you can get what you want as following steps
1) prepare a png image with the shape you want and fill it with color 0x0000000
2) use a blank layout and make sure it covers the VideView
3) now, all touchevents are captured by this blank layout
4) judge the points' colors which are contained in TouchEvent, if the color is 0x00000000  then pass the event to VideView

here is a example to get a point's color, and it runs efficently:

```
// build a drawingCache and draw the mask layer to the bitmap
        Bitmap drawingCache = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
        Canvas drawingCacheCanvas = new Canvas(drawingCache);
        drawingCacheCanvas.clipRect(x, y, x + 1, y + 1); 
        draw(drawingCacheCanvas);

        int color = drawingCache.getPixel(x, y);

        if (color == getMaskColor()) { 
            //TODO dispatch event to VideoView and let it to handle event
        }
```