# Play video in a circular view in android

Tags: video, view

Can any one suggest me how i can play a video in circle view mean how i can create video view as a circle where the video will be play , and how to create custom video view in android.

Comment: Have implemented circle `videoview`? If you implements means, Please share your idea how to do it

Comment: Did you implemented circle videoview? Please share your ideas

Answer (score 1):

I have added an circular Transparent image on Top of videoView .And it look like circular videoView. but it is rectangular instead. And the transparent image on Top of it shows. [See here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.crmxperts.AsmaUlHusna) and [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.crmxperts.AsmaUnNabi)

Comment: links are broken

Comment: @ZaidMirza that account is banned