# How to create rounded corner surfaceview in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, surfaceview, android-videoview

I want to make a surface view which can have rounded corners. This surface view will be useful to render the video camera.

I have already tried adding the surface view in the CardView with this code.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cvCard"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="false">

    <Surfaceview is Added Programatically>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The result of this code is this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlRLd.jpg). As you can see in the round corners the surface view is still visible. It is not entirely round within the card view and it always comes in rectangle shape.

So is there any way to achieve the rounded corner Surfaceview?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a rounded surfaceview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36564025/how-to-make-a-rounded-surfaceview)

Answer (score -1):

You can not change directly `surface view` corner (Shape). But you can change your `CardView` corner by using

```
app:cardCornerRadius="10dp" 
app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
```

and set the `SurfaceView` `match_parent` that can cover the `cardView`.

Why you cannot change surface view shape?
The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36583173/6875716)