# Android round surface view for video recording

Tags: android, surfaceview, geometry, rounding

Is there a possibility to have a round surface view instead a rectangle one? If the output is  640x480 it isnt a problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking -- can't you just put a mask over the SurfaceView?

Comment: Put the SurfaceView into a FrameLayout, then put another View on top of it, either with a PNG mask, or a shape xml drawable...

Comment: It worked thanks! Had to call the bringToFront()! I used a relative layout instead of a frame layout!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the SurfaceView into a FrameLayout, then put another View on top of it, either with a PNG mask, or a shape xml drawable.

Comment: Is there a clever way to do this, but then add elevation and circular shadows to the circular video that look half decent (material design) :(

Comment: @Lo-Tan: I'd use a 9-patch to build the mask (with the shadow you desire) and use that on top of the SurfaceView.

Comment: I was actually able to clip the surface view to a circle by extending the class and overriding dispatchDraw (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14294979/269876) This allowed me to only have one view for my video view, which made elevation and shadow much more straight forward.  :)  Thanks!

Comment: Although the anti aliasing (or lack thereof) is kind of rough and I might instead resort to a mask & nine patch anyway...

Comment: @Lo-Tan Thanks your link. And there is a full example of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31064523/1819810

Answer (score 0):

Simply add surfaceview inside of Cardview and add below parameters :

```
app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_200sdp"
app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.daasuu.sample.SquareActivity">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_12sdp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_200sdp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

    <!--Add here surfaceview or textureview -->

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
  


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```